# Integrate the following $\int\frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

Integrate the following $\int\frac{x+1}{x(1+xe^x)^2}dx$

I tried to multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{-2x}$

Getting the following simplification
$\int\frac{e^{-2x}(x+1)}{x(e^{-x}+x)^2}dx$

My next step is as follow $\int\frac{e^{-2x}(x+1)}{x^3(\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+1)^2})dx$
 but could not proceed from here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
let $$u=1+xe^x\rightarrow xe^x=u-1$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{e^x(1+x)}$$
substitute them to get
$$\int\frac{1}{u^2(u-1)}du$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write your integrand in the form$$-\frac{e^x x+e^x}{e^x x+1}-\frac{e^x x+e^x}{\left(e^x x+1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{x}+1$$